# Does the Chrome's V8 Javascript engine handle delete operator correctly?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

```js
function MyObject() {
  this.propA = 'hello';
}
alert(MyObject instanceof Object) // true, All JavaScript objects (Date, Array, RegExp, Function, ....) inherit from the Object.prototype.

alert({}.name); // undefined, empty object(or Object.prototype) has no name
alert({}.propA); //undefined, empty object has no propA

alert(delete MyObject.propA); //true, function object's propA is deletable.
alert(MyObject.propA); //  undefined.

alert(delete MyObject.name); //true, function object's name is deletable.
alert(MyObject.name); //empty string in chrome
```

I have put my logic in the comments of above javascript snippet. 
Basically, my thought is like this:

1. Function is Object according to W3School
2. Object doesn't have a property called "name"(undefined)
3. according to MDN, the description section of delete operator says "The delete operator removes a given property from an object." So if my function object's name property is removed, there is no "name" property at Function level, shouldn't it be using the property from its prototype chain, which is undefined for Object?
4. It turned out true for a custom defined property(undefined after deletion), but for the "name" property, it returned empty string after deletion.
5. Internet Explorer from Microsoft return undefined in both cases, so it's a browser issue, and I believe the definition of delete (or remove) a property is not ambiguous, neither is the prototype chain between function and object. Can someone justify Chrome's implementation of delete operator?

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/yww325/2866a1gb/

Reference:

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_prototypes.asp

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does the Chrome's V8 Javascript engine handle delete operator correctly?

Yes.

You're deleting the `name` property from `MyObject`. But `MyObject`'s *prototype* (the object `Function.prototype` refers to) *also* has a `name` property, because (for mostly historic reasons) `Function.prototype` is a function. That's what you're seeing for `MyObject.name` after the `delete`: The `name` from its prototype (since when you look up a property on an object, if it doesn't have that property, the JavaScript engine looks to its prototype, and then to *its* prototype, etc., to try to find it).

If you add `hasOwnProperty` checks in your last couple of lines, you can see what's going on:

```js
function MyObject() {
this.propA ='hello';
} 
console.log(MyObject instanceof  Object) // true, All JavaScript objects (Date, Array, RegExp, Function, ....) inherit from the Object.prototype.

console.log({}.name); // undefined, empty object(or Object.prototype) has no name
console.log({}.propA); //undefined, empty object has no propA

console.log(delete MyObject.propA); //true, function object's propA is deletable.
console.log(MyObject.propA); //  undefined.

console.log("own check 1: " + MyObject.hasOwnProperty("name")); // true, it has an own property
console.log(delete MyObject.name); //true, function object's name is deletable.
console.log("own check 2: " + MyObject.hasOwnProperty("name")); // false, now it's coming from the prototype
console.log(MyObject.name); //empty string in chrome
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

> Function is Object according to W3School

Functions are indeed objects, but there's more to the story: They're objects with another prototype between themselves and `Object.prototype`. Here's what things look like *before* the `delete`:

```
+−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
|     MyObject      |
+−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+    +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
| [[Prototype]]     |−−−>| Function.prototype |
| name: "MyObject"  |    +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+    +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
+−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+    | [[Prototype]]      |−−−>| Object.prototype    |
                         | name: ""           |    +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                         +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+    | [[Prototype]]: null |
                                                   +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
```

and then after, the only change is in `MyObject`:

```
+−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
|     MyObject      |
+−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+    +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
| [[Prototype]]     |−−−>| Function.prototype |
+−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+    +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+    +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                         | [[Prototype]]      |−−−>| Object.prototype    |
                         | name: ""           |    +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                         +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+    | [[Prototype]]: null |
                                                   +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
```

---

> Internet Explorer from Microsoft return undefined in both cases, so it's a browser issue

The `name` property on functions is relatively new (ES2015), defined long after IE11 was released. IE11 [doesn't support it](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-function_name_property) (after following that link, sadly you have to scroll up slightly). Don't be surprised if you find JavaScript engines that don't quite support the `name` property on functions yet, or have older legacy handling of it. Recent versions of Chrome handle it properly. IE, not at all.

---

Side note: You have this code in there:

```
console.log(delete MyObject.propA); //true, function object's propA is deletable.
```

I feel I should point out that `MyObject` doesn't have any property called `propA`. If you used `new MyObject`, the object created by the `new` operator would have a `propA` (because `MyObject` creates one), or if you caled `MyObject` without `new` in loose mode you'd create a global `propA`, but neither of those will create a `propA` on `MyObject`. `delete` returns `true` on that line because [`delete` on ordinary objects](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-ordinarydelete) returns `true` if the property doesn't exist on the object.

Comment: Thank you T.J. I didn't know that delete return true when the property doesn't exist(how strange that is!) and IE11 doesn't support the name property.  And the reason I didn't use "new" to create an object is I want to check the relation between Function and Object, I think if I create an object using new, then it's not Function but an Object. But yes, that way I didn't set custom property to function(I thought I did because deleting it returned true, that fooled me)